# Kill all Internet Explorer processes that have been running for more than 5 minutes using Powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, process, kill

I would like to kill all Internet Explorer processes that have been running more than 5 minutes. This has to be a command in one line using Powershell v1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way:

```
 get-process iexplore | ? { ([DateTime]::Now - $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds -gt 300 } | stop-process
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Where-Object { $_.StartTime -and (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) -gt $_.StartTime } |
Stop-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

At least at powershell v2 following command should stop all IE processes older then 5 minutes:

```
Get-Process | 
    select -Property ProcessName, StartTime |
    ? { (($_.StartTime -ne $null) -and
         (([DateTime]::Now - $_.StartTime).TotalMinutes -ge 5) -and
         ($_.ProcessName -eq "iexplore")) } |
    Stop-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first process only, with high CPU usage :

```
get-process iexplore | sort –descending cpu | select –First 1 | stop-process
```

Comment: This does answer the question!