# PDF to Excel error when closing PDF file

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a code to transfer PDF files to Excel but I'm getting an error message in one of the lines and I don't know why.

I'm able to extract and paste the data from the PDF correctly, the problem is when trying to close the PDF file.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
 (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
 ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub PDFExtract()

' Get name of Excel file
TemplateName = ThisWorkbook.Name

Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")
FileToOpen = "c:\text.pdf"
ShellExecute 0, "Open", FileToOpen, "", "", vbNormalNoFocus
num = ShellExecute(0, "Open", FileToOpen, "", "", vbNormalNoFocus)

' wait 2 secs
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

' select all using ctrl a
SendKeys "^a", True

' wait 2 secs
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

' copy all using ctrl c
SendKeys "^c"

' wait 2 secs
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

' activate this wokbook
Windows(TemplateName).Activate
Sheets("Temp").Select
Range("B7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Call TerminateApp ' The problem in the code for TerminateApp
End sub
```

So far so good. Now the TerminateApp code where I have the problem

```
Sub TerminateApp()

Dim strTerminateThis As String

Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object, objProcess As Object, objList As Object
Dim intError As Integer

strTerminateThis = "AcroRd32.exe"

Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & strTerminateThis & "'")
For Each objProcess In objList
    intError = objProcess.Terminate '<<< Here is where I get the error message
    If intError <> 0 Then Exit For
Next

'ALL instances of exe (strTerminateThis) have been terminated
Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
Set objList = Nothing
Set objProcess = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've highlighted above where I'm getting the error message. The error message I'm getting is: Run-time error '-2147217406 (80041002): Not found

What I found strange is that:

- The PDF file has been closed
- If I step over the line, the program
  continues with no error
- If I have another PDF file open, it closes
  both and does not give an error message

It looks like it closes the PDF file and then tries to look for it but does not find it. Any ideas why the error appears and how to resolve the problem?

I tried to modify the code as per example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167647/terminating-all-explorer-instances-via-vba-excel) from [smartbelix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7047935/smartobelix) but it didn't work:

```
Do
    Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & strTerminateThis & "'")
    If objList.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objProcess In objList
            intError = objProcess.Terminate 'Terminates a process and all of its threads.
            'Return value is 0 for success. Any other number is an error.
            If intError <> 0 Then Exit For
        Next
    End If
Loop While objList.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your `Function ShellExecute`, add these two:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

And then here is the `TerminateApp` code:

```
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim nRet As Long

Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10

hWnd = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", vbNullString)

If hWnd <> 0 Then
    nRet = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
End If
```

Try and let me know if this works or not.

P.S. I only tested with one PDF open and close.

Comment: Perfect, that does the job. Where there are two PDFs files, only the one that I have open previously in PDFExtract is closed. But this is actually perfect. Thanks very much.